# How to customize the Nokia Here marker bubble?

Tags: here-api, infobubble

I use Nokia Here map and I want to customize the marker bubble.

When I click on the marker, it opens a popup with some datas.

I would like to know if it's possible to change the popup design, like the black color and other ? And if so, how can I do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the latest **HERE Maps for JavaScript API 3.0**, the `Infobubble` content is held within a `<div class="H_ib_body">` element  (This used to be a `<div class='nm_bubble_content'>` element for the old **2.5.4 API**) so it is possible to restyle the content of every bubble by applying a CSS style to the class

e.g.

```
.H_ib_body{
  color:black;
  background:white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding:0px;
}
```

Alternatively, since the **content** within the Infobubble in both the old [2.5.4 API](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/maps/topics_api_pub/nokia.maps.map.component.InfoBubbles.html) (`nokia.maps.map.component.InfoBubbles`) and the new [3.0 API](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-ui-infobubble.html) (`H.ui.InfoBubble`) is itself HTML, you are not restricted to passing a string, you could pass a `<div>` yourself, and style the content of an individual bubble using standard CSS (or an inline style)

A fuller explanation can be found at http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/HERE_Maps_API_-_How_to_create_a_tabbed_Infobubble